# Clojure: delete item from a ref?

Tags: clojure

I created the ref "people" below, and want the function delete-person to delete an item from the data structure within a transaction.

```
(defrecord Person [name favorite-color])

(def people (ref ()))

(defn add-person [new-person]
  (dosync
    (alter people conj new-person)))

(add-person (Person. "Joe" "Red"))
(add-person (Person. "Sam" "Blue"))

;; how do I make this function work? 
;; would @people (destructured) have to be the second argument to filter? 
(defn delete-person [name-to-delete]
  "Delete named person from ref"
  (dosync
    (alter people filter #(not= (:name %) name-to-delete))))

(delete-person "Joe")

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: 
user$delete_person$fn__1407$fn__1408  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

The function below works because I filter on the destructured ref, but how do I do it in a transaction to mutate the data?

```
   (filter #(not= (:name %) "Sam") @people)
=> (#user.Person{:name "Joe", :favorite-color "Red"})
```

Answer (score 4):

As there error says, you're trying to iterate a function. This is coming about because when you write:

```
(alter people filter #(not= (:name %) name-to-delete))
```

The unwrapped `people` becomes the *first* argument to `filter`, not the last.

You'll need to use an full `fn`, or use `partial`:

```
(alter people
    (fn [ps] (filter #(not= (:name %) name-to-delete) ps)))
```

Or

```
(alter people
    (partial filter #(not= (:name %) name-to-delete)))
```

These make `alter` pass the unwrapped `people` as the last argument to `filter`, instead of implicitly as the first.

---

I'll note though:

- As @cfrick brought up in the comments, using lazy sequences in a transaction *may* have the potential to cause problems. I can't offhand think of a scenario where it would, but it *feels* wrong. It could be argued that the realization of a lazy sequence is a side effect, and side effects shouldn't take place in a transaction, since transactions may run multiple times in the event of a conflict. Multiple realizations shouldn't cause a problem, but I can't say definitively that it's safe (honestly, I never use `ref`s).
- Make sure you actually need `ref`s and transactions here. Transactions are for when you need to sequence multiple alterations to data, and need to be able to catch when the data involved has been changed part way through a transaction. If you just need a simple mutable container though, `atom` are much simpler.

Comment: I swear i have never use ref in the real world.  Is it "safe" to have a lazy sequence stored up in the ref?

Comment: @cfrick I'm not sure. I never use them either. I can't offhand think of a scenario where it would cause a problem though. If the filtering function itself caused side effects, ya, that would be bad. It could be argued that realizing a lazy sequence is a side effect, but I can't think of how that specific side effect would cause problems in a transaction. Maybe I'll add a note if I can think of a good way to word it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Switching to atoms instead of refs. Very new to Clojure and I had misunderstood atoms as being for scalars, but I see that I can store a mutable list of maps in an atom. Very helpful.

Comment: @BillO'Brien Np. And I hope you mean an *immutable* list in the atom. If you have a *mutable* Java list, putting it in an atom doesn't gain you anything since it's mutable already. Atoms are a mutable container to hold immutable objects that allow atomic operations to be carried out on their contents.

Comment: The main issue with using laziness here is that if you call delete many times without reading, or adding to, the list, your many pending filter calls will stack up. Try `(do (dotimes [_ 1e5] (delete-person "steve")) (count @people))` and make sure you can explain why you get the result you do.